# Cannot access tumblr's API console

Tags: api, authentication, oauth, console, tumblr

For some strange reason, I can no longer access tumblr's API console:

https://api.tumblr.com/console//calls/user/info

It takes me to the authorize page, but once I click "allow" I just get redirected back to the login page. Strangely nothing has changed, my python script still has access. I tried creating a new account, new app, on a new IP. But I still can't get into that stupid console!

Answer (score 0):

I got an email from the developers at tumblr, it looks like they fixed the problem:

> My apologies for the extremely late response. We had an issue with this page which has since been fixed.
>
> Hope it didn't cause you too much trouble!